# Send with java a message with message header + InetAddress but getting different result than expected

Tags: java, c

I know that `InetAddress` is 4 bytes long. Is it possible to make it 16 bytes long? I need it 16 bytes long and then i need to send it over an `OutputStream` on a local unix socket. Thanks!

The c application expects a `struct sockaddr_in` type which has a size of 16 bytes.

i tried using `byte[] ipBytes = InetAddress.getByName("153.16.12.1").getAddress();` which correctly sends 4 bytes, but i need the equvalent in 16 bytes (as if it were a sockaddr_in that was sending the data 16 bytes long). I tried sending both data i c and java hoping to get the same outpt but thats not the case.

EDIT: these are the 2 outputs i get. The first which was generated by a c codded file and sends the data correctly whereas the second case is me trying to send the same data but with java. I dont think its a problem of eindianess as most of the characters are in the correct position or are near.

I recieved n bytes: 44

```
[ 68 01 07 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 1f ec 2d 7f 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 99 10 0c 01 60 05 40 00 00 00 00 00 ]
```

I recieved n bytes: 48

```
[ 68 01 07 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 99 10 0c 01 ]
```

Strangely im getting 4 extra bytes also. Why?

Comment: Add 12 bytes of padding.  If you had something specific in mind, you need to provide more details.

Comment: well on the receiving side i have a server codded in c which expects a particular header + a sockaddr_in address (only ip address). I managed to make the header but not the ip address as InetAddress is 4 bytes and sockaddr_in is 16 bytes.

Comment: you need to determine what the format of the `sockaddr_in` is as you say it's not an IPv4 address, but that doesn't tell us what it is.  Without knowing it's format, it's not possible to guess what it should be.

Comment: its originally a struct sockaddr_storage. I know that this is a very general format and that usually u need to cast it say to struct sockaddr_in. Now Im only interested in the ipaddress value. I tried printing the bytes and i get different results if i send an ipaddress via java InetAddress (byte[] ipBytes = InetAddress.getByName("1.1.1.1").getAddress();) and c sockeaddr_in (where i specify the family as AF_INET and the address say 1.1.1.1). What more of a format is there to know in this case. i just need the address.

Comment: are you actually saying that you need to transfer architecture-specific, OS-specific, language-specific, alignment-specific data structures between completely different languages?? Son ... your problems wont end here, your receiving end obviously has been developed by someone who does not know how to develop software. I recommend replacing the c app with something which actually works.

Comment: What do you want to have in those upper 12 bytes? Zeros? Ones? Something else? When you answer that question, I'm sure you will figure out the solution yourself.

Comment: oh no.....on the receiving side he is actually waiting for this and then casts based on what it recieves: union sockunion {
 struct  sockaddr sa;
 struct  sockaddr_in sin;
 struct  sockaddr_in6 sin6;
 struct  sockaddr_storage ss;
}; more than this i dont know :(

Comment: thats *exactly* what i just said. Btw : who is "he"?

Comment: im doomed then i guess. i cant chande the c code as it does many more things. i dont know what else to do

Comment: thats easy : replace the c app with something which actually works.

Comment: can't do. the c app does many more things that i need

Comment: well you need to contact the original developer and ask him to fix it then. Transferring structs over sockets never works reliably - because its WAY too specific to be useful, thats why things like "serialization" have been invented. Ask him to take programming classes or something, he obviously needs them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing you want to pass an IPv4 address over IPv6.  There is a technique called [IPv4 over Ipv6 address mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6#IPv4-mapped_IPv6_addresses) Where you pass the IPv4 address as the lower bits of an address like this

> For example, ::ffff:192.0.2.128 represents the IPv4 address 192.0.2.128

Comment: So i tried a few test cases with the c code server and it actually expects Ipv4 over Ipv6 address mapping as Peter mentioned. So im sending from java a Inet6Address, but still from the c application it can not read the ip address i sent.

Comment: @Pheonix7 how are your writing the IPv6 number? Are you using little endian?

Comment: i dont know which one i need. I can try one or the other if i have some sample code

Comment: i edited the question showing the 2 different outputs i get